# Apache rewrite condition goes to infinite loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, tomcat, mod-rewrite

I have a tomcat with two application named “app1” and “app2”. 
I have fronted Apache web server for tomcat with following v.host configuration.

```
ServerName mywebapp.com
ServerAlias mywebapp.com

ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia On

<Proxy *>
AddDefaultCharset Off
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>

RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebapp.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mywebapp.com/app1$1 [R=301,L]

ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/
```

I can access my both webapps with following URLs.

- mywebapp.com/app1
- mywebapp.com/app2

I need one default redirect rule where, if user hit “**mywebapp.com**” it redirect to “**mywebapp.com/app1**”

I have tried following one but no luck. it goes to infinite loop.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebapp.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mywebapp.com/app1$1 [R=301,L]
```

Can anyone plz suggest me the changes I need to do?

Comment: Why are you redirecting your domain to itself?

Comment: B'Coz I need my "app1" as default web-app on mywebapp.com bydefault. That is why i'm redirecting mywebapp.com to mywebapp.com/app1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebapp.com$
RewriteRule ^/?((?!app1).*)$ http://mywebapp.com/app1/$1 [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: @startkeen : After adding these lines. I'm landing to Apache default page.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} = mywebapp.com
RewriteRule .* /app1 [R=302]
```

redirect 301 is permanent. Unless you want it to be permanent don't use it.
redirect 302 is temporary and it is the default.

Comment: You are matching against Http_host  using %{REQUEST_URI} variable.